# Designing a Battery Management System

Tags: power-electronics, battery-charging, lithium-ion

We have been asked to design a Battery management system that gets the state of charge while plugged in or not for a prototype EV with 5 batteries in series each 12 V 50 Ah. I've tried looking for such a project online and on youtube but couldn't find anything to help me or I just didn't get it

I did extensive research on how to charge lithium-ion batteries, to charge the 5 batteries in the shortest amount of time safely, I decided to charge them at 60 V and 10 A.

I'm focusing mostly on the main challenge of getting the state of charge, I have been actively searching for an IC on the market(for 2 weeks now)  mostly from JLCPCB and I'm also looking at Texas Instruments ,that can handle 60 V at 10 A . It must also have SDA for I2C communication so that I can hook it up to a microcontroller which would give me charge state of charge, using this data to open the circuit with a relay when the battery is full(also to display the battery percentage).

Here's what I found what I found:

1.
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/29411f.pdf

This IC can handle 60 V but I think it can't handle currents above 800 mA-1 A unless I didn't read it right

2.
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1805311218_Analog-Devices-LTC4013EUFD-PBF_C107935.pdf

I was excited to find this one because it met my needs but it doesn't seem to support SDA I2C communication , And from the data sheet I can't seem to find any other way to get the SOC

I'm still searching but:

- what charge voltage or current would you propose?
- Is using such an IC for this single task the best method or is their a tradition method that works?
- Do you know of any IC's that can do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the charger task from the SoC measurements and calculation job. There is nothing to win if you design a charger for a prototype EV. Also you cannot simply consider 60 V, 10 A as the fastest possible safe condition without carefully reading the battery datasheet.

Then find a coulomb counter IC sometimes called "gas gauge". This will count the charge going into and coming out of the battery. Together with the battery voltage and temperature a state of charge can be estimated. Since the initial state is unknown, the algorithm can adjust the calculation if an empty state or fully charged condition is recognized.

This may be good enough, because people are accustomed to wrong SoC displays everywhere. A clever algorithm recalculates the true capacity of the battery dynamically, which will be lower over time.

So you will have a state of charge relative to the original capacity of the battery and a value relative to the remaining capacity.

There are ICs, that contain such an algorithm. It is also possible to implement this in an MCU and just fetch values from coulomb counters and ADCs. Testing this can be a bit frustrating, patience is required while watching many charge and discharge cycles.

Comment: thankyou! I did carefully read it's datasheet but couldn't get the charging current though similar batteries with the same specs are often charged at 10A(Got this from other datasheets of these batteries) 

But what did you mean when you said separate the charger task from the Soc measurement?

Comment: I just wanted to say, that a charger is an external device and the SoC calculation is a job for the battery pack. You should be open to use different available charger models and not look for a specific charger IC, that contains SoC features.

Comment: Ohh I get it ,  you just opened my mind , thanks a tone

Answer (score 1):

Proper battery management must handle many parameters, cases, and eventualities, most of which you didn't even know needed to be addresses. A design error can result in a fire, which is particularly scary in an EV. Therefore, I always recommend to buy an off-the-shelf BMS: well designed, cheaper, meets regulations, guaranteed to work, gets you up and running in hours, not months. For example, lately I have been impressed by the [Wattius BMS](https://wattius.com/web/).

Also, consider an off-the shelf Li-ion battery with an integral BMS. There are [many off-the-shelf 12 V 50 Ah Li-ion batteries](https://www.google.com/search?q=12V+50AH+Li-ion+battery), including [some with I2C communications](http://en.topakpower.com/product-center/2302.html).

Comment: I think he is asking about putting 5 of those 12V batteries in series. That would roughly add up to the 60V at least. Of course the 12V battery itself is already a series connection of cells...

Comment: @Lars Hankeln Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @DavideAndrea  thanks , I think the safe option is great , but we have been assigned to design these systems from scratch but has you mentioned it's dangerous . They'd have to undergo vigorous testing